# How to swap two nodes of XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my source XML,

```
    <Employee>
       <Position>
          <Operation>ADD</Operation>
          <ID>9876</ID>
       <Position>
       <Position>
          <Operation>REMOVE</Operation>
          <ID>1234</ID>
       <Position>
    <Employee>
```

Need to transform the above code to the below code,

```
    <Employee>
       <Position>
          <Operation>REMOVE</Operation>
          <ID>1234</ID>
       <Position>
       <Position>
          <Operation>ADD</Operation>
          <ID>9876</ID>
       <Position>
    <Employee>
```

Basically need to swap such that position with REMOVE appears first and ADD appears next.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try to do? What is your environment, API, etc? What is working, and what is not? And you XML is not well-formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT. It is using so called Identity transform pattern.

A template for the **Employee** element specifies a sequential order for the **Position** elements based on their child element **Operation** value.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employee>
    <Position>
        <Operation>ADD</Operation>
        <ID>9876</ID>
    </Position>
    <Position>
        <Operation>REMOVE</Operation>
        <ID>1234</ID>
    </Position>
</Employee>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match='Employee'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Position[Operation='REMOVE']"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Position[Operation='ADD']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employee>
  <Position>
    <Operation>REMOVE</Operation>
    <ID>1234</ID>
  </Position>
  <Position>
    <Operation>ADD</Operation>
    <ID>9876</ID>
  </Position>
</Employee>
```

Comment: @ArunPrakash, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to accept it as Answer.